# Manage a python application using pm2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pm2

I have a Python 3 application with the following structure:

```
application
  |
  - application.json
  |
  - package
  |  |
  |  - __init__.py
  |  - module1.py
  |  - module2.py
  |
  - test_package
  |  |
  |  - __init__.py
  |  - test_module1.py
  |  - test_module2.py
  |
  - conf
  |  |
  |  - package.conf
  |
  - log
  | |
  | - module1.log
  | - module2.log
  |
  - virtualenv    (Python 3 virtual environment)
    |
    - bin
    | |
    | - python
    | - activate
    | - ...
    |
    - ...
```

It needs to be launched as follows from the `application` directory (in the example assume your working directory is `/path/to/application/`):

```
/path/to/application/virtualenv/bin/python -m package.module1
```

or

```
virtualenv/bin/python -m package.module1
```

This application runs a back-end service on a server, and I would like to manage it with PM2, since I already use it to manage a Node.js based web site in the server.

I have tried using the following environment file (`application.json`) without success, and I can't figure out what is wrong with it:

```
{
    "name": "application",
    "script": "/path/to/application/virtualenv/bin/python",
    "args": "-u -m package.module1",
    "cwd": "/path/to/application/",
    "instances": 1,
    "autorestart": true,
    "watch": true,
    "max_memory_restart": "1G",
    "pid": "/path/to/application/log/application.pid",
    "out_file": "/path/to/application/log/application_out_file.log",
    "error_file": "/path/to/application/log/application_error_file.log"
}
```

When I run the `pm2 start application.json`, the app starts, crashes after one iteration of its inner loop, and then it starts restarting and crashing over and over again before completing a single iteration of the inner loop. Then, I run an `pm2 stop application` command, and the application starts running as it should ¯_(ツ)_/¯. Running the `pm2 stop application` command again does stop the app, and `delete` works too.

I also tried to use the `interpreter` and `interpreter-args` as stated in the PM2 documentation, but I am already calling the interpreter in my script, so that does not work.

How should I call my script so that I don't get this weird behavior? What is the recommended way to call a python script that needs to be called using `python -m package.module`?

#### Edit

Using the following command from the `application` directory seems to work:

```
pm2 start '/path/to/application/virtualenv/bin/python -u -m package.module1'
```

How can I translate this into a configuration file for PM2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was the issue. The environment file (`application.json`) had the `watch` field set to `true`. This setting watches if there are any file changes in the application's folder or subfolders (for my example, the `application` folder and subfolders). [Here is the documentation on that feature](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#advanced-features).

The logs are included in the folder `application/log/`, which is a subfolder of `application`. As soon as anything was written to the logs, PM2 detected that, and it reloaded the application. Disabling this setting fixed all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add to consider setting the option --ignore-watch. For example you could add to application.json

`"ignore_watch": ["log"],`

instead of disabling watch mode.

For more information: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/

Comment: finally found this after so many hours, great !